# Separate thermostat power source from HVAC unit for home battery backup

Tags: hvac, furnace, thermostat-c-wire, power-backup

Here's my situation.  I have two HVAC units connected to Ecobee smart thermostats.  Both have C wires and were standard installs.

We are having solar panels and an Enphase backup battery system installed with a backed-up loads panel and non-backed-up loads panel in the garage.  The HVAC units cannot run when we are on battery backup power because they pull too much current and will overload the system, so they must be connected to the non-backed-up panel.

The issue is that the main breaker panel that supplies power to everything, including both HVAC units is in the middle of the house and the **wiring** is not accessible because of a second floor addition above that area.  The thermostats however are both in an area accessible via the attic.  I would like to run a separate line from the non-backed up panel from the garage to the attic to power just the thermostats via 24V transformers such that when running on backup battery power, the thermostats are not powered and therefore, the HVAC units cannot run.

I have looked at how the thermostats are wired and see that it is not as trivial as just switching two power connections from one source to another.

Comment: You state, "the main breaker panel that supplies power to everything, including both HVAC units is in the middle of the house and the wiring is not accessible because of a second floor addition above that area." What would you ever do if a circuit breaker tripped, if you cannot access it? As for the thermostats, they probably are powered from a single 24 VAC source -- just put a relay in series with the 24 V wiring, and control it by the switchover of power from mains to inverter.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - I was just going to suggest the same.  I was in the same situation and the solar installers were freaking out with my suggestions.  So, I added the relays after they had gone.

Comment: Does the Enphase battery system provide support for more...dynamic load shedding?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The breaker panel is accessible, I think you are reading that wrong.  What I'm saying is that we can't just run new wiring from the new non backed up loads panel in the garage to the main panel in the house and tie into the HVAC wiring without ripping out drywall in half of the house because much of it is in the ceiling below a second story.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel No, battery systems do not support dynamic load shedding, they just supply power to a panel.  You accomplish this by having 2 panels, 1 for loads backed up by batteries and one for non backed up loads.  But like I stated, I'm trying to effectively make the HVAC units non backed up without having to run new wiring by just switching the thermostats to the non backed up panel.